# Apache server seems to be caching requests

Tags: apache, flask, python-requests

I am running a Flask app on an Apache 2.4 server. The app sends requests to an API built by a colleague using the Requests library. The requests are in a specific format and constructed by data stored in a MySQL database. The site is designed to show the feedback from the API on the index, and the user can edit the data stored in the MySQL database (and by extension, the data sent in the request) by another page, the editing page.

So let's say for example a custom field `date` is set to be `"2006"`, I would access the index page, a request would be sent, the API does its magic and sends back data relevant to 2006. If I then went and changed the date to `"2007"` then the new field is saved in MySQL and upon navigating back to index the new request is constructed, sent off and data for 2007 should be returned.

Unfortunately that's not happening.

My when I change details on my editing page they are definitely stored to the database, but when I navigate back to the index the request sends the previous set of data. I think that Apache is causing the problem because of two reasons:

1. When I reset the server (`service apache2 restart`) the data sent back is the 'proper' data, even though I haven't touched the database. That is, the index is initially requesting 2006 data, I change it to request 2007 data, it still requests 2006 data, I restart the server, refresh the index and only *then* does it request 2007 data like it should have been doing since I edited it.
2. When I run this on my local Flask development server, navigating to the index page after editing an entry immediately returns the right result - it feeds off the same database and is essentially identical to the deployed server except that it's not running on apache.

Is there a way that Apache could be caching requests or something? I can't figure out why the server would keep sending old requests until I restart it.

**EDIT:**
The requests themselves are large and ungainly and the responses would return data that I'm not comfortable with making available for examples for privacy reasons.

I am almost certain that Apache is the issue because as previously stated, the Flask development server has no issues with returning the correct dataset. I have also written some requests to run through Postman, and these also return the data as requested, so the request structure must be fine. The only difference I can see between the local Flask app and the deployed one is Apache, and given that restarting the Apache server 'updates' the requests until the data is changed again, I think that it's quite clearly doing something untoward.

Comment: Are you sure it's Apache? How are you loading the data in your application? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38854382/edit) the question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Dirn was completely right, it turned out not to be an Apache issue at all. It was SQL Alchemy all along.

I imagine that SQL Alchemy knows not to do any 'caching' when it requests data on the development server but decides that it's a good idea in production, which makes perfect sense really. It was not using the committed data on every search, which  is why restarting the Apache server fixed it because it also reset the connection.

I guess that's what dirn meant by "How are you loading data in your application?" I had assumed that since I turned off Flask's debugging on the development server it would behave just like it would in deployment but it looks like something has slipped through.